# How do I resolve 'expected struct, found reference` for borrowed value?

Tags: rust

I get an error referencing a boxed value:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/interpreter.rs:284:37
    |
284 |             table[index].function = method;
    |                                     ^^^^^^ expected struct `Box`, found `&Box<MethodType>`
    |
    = note: expected struct `Box<MethodType>`
            found reference `&Box<MethodType>`
```

If I dereference it by saying `*method` I get an error because `MethodType` doesn't implement `Copy` (which would be a pain, because it includes a couple of `Vec`s and it would be very expensive to copy). Maybe I could fix it with `ManuallyDrop`, but that doesn't seem very idiomatic, and I spent some time this afternoon getting rid of a `ManuallyDrop`.

Perhaps I shouldn't be passing it by reference (the only two calls to `addMethodToTable` are in the following method, `addMethodToDispatch` but they are in loops, because I need to try allocation several times). Maybe it should be an `Rc` instead.
This is part of a lot of code, so I hope this snippit is enough to show what I'm doing wrong:

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
enum MethodType {
    Function(Function),
    Method(Method),
    NoType,
}
#[derive(Clone)]
struct MethodMatch {
    selector: usize,
    function: Box<MethodType>,
}
pub struct Dispatch {
    class: Object,
    table: Box<[MethodMatch]>,
}
fn addMethodToTable(table:&mut Vec<MethodMatch>,selector:usize,method:&Box<MethodType>) -> bool {
    let len = table.capacity();
    let hash = selector%(len-DISPATCH_OVERFLOW);
    for index in hash..hash+DISPATCH_OVERFLOW {
        if let SelectorMatch::Other = table[index].selector_match(selector) {
            // slot taken
        } else {
            table[index].selector = selector;
            table[index].function = method;
            return true
        }
    }
    false
}
fn addMethodToDispatch(class:ClassIndex,selector:Object,method:Box<MethodType>) {
    let selector = selector.raw()>>3;
    while ... {
                    table = Vec::with_capacity(count+DISPATCH_OVERFLOW);
                    addMethodToTable(&mut table,selector,&method);
                    for mm in disp.table.iter() {
                        if addMethodToTable(&mut table,mm.selector,&mm.function) {unfinished = true;break}
                    }
                }
                table.resize(table.capacity(),Default::default());
                disp.table=table.into_boxed_slice()
            },
            index => {
                disp.table[index].selector = selector;
                disp.table[index].function = method
            },
```

I was having such a productive day until I hit this... thinking I was finally "getting" Rust!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your struct expects an **owned** type - `function` must be a `Box`:

```
#[derive(Clone)]
struct MethodMatch {
    selector: usize,
    function: Box<MethodType>,
}
```

but in your other method the parameter `method` is a reference to a `Box` which are two very different types:

```
`fn addMethodToTable(....,method: &Box<MethodType>)
```

There are two ways to fix the issue (not all may be applicable in your case):

1. Change the reference to an owned type: `method: &Box<MethodType>` should become `method: Box<MethodType>`
2. Because your `MethodType` implements `Clone`, just clone it in order to get an owned type from the reference: `table[index].function = method.clone();`
3. If you are free to change the struct definition, you can use `Rc<T>` instead of `Box<T>`. Thus you can use `Rc::clone(reference)` and clone only the pointer instead of the whole struct.

Comment: #1 didn't work because I had to pass a reference (that was the type-hell I was in already when I asked the question)

Comment: #2 did solve the problem, thanks. I wasn't keen on cloning, though as it would potentially be fairly expensive. So I put an Rc into the structure to ameliorate that, and it's all good now.

Comment: @DaveMason If you are in control of that part of the code, you can use `Rc` instead of `Box`. Thus you will not need to clone the whole struct in case it's large.

Comment: Thanks @Svetlin Zarev, it looks like we entered our comments almost simultaneously!